# Split date range in weeks in oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to split the following data in Oracle SQL:

```
WITH sample_data AS
      (SELECT DATE '2020-12-16' Start_Date, DATE '2021-01-07' End_Date FROM DUAL)
```

in week ranges for every working week(from Monday to Friday) of this given period. The final result it should look like this:

```
NEW_STARTDATE  NEW_END_DATE
2020-12-16     2020-12-18
2020-12-21     2020-12-25
2020-12-28     2021-01-01
2021-01-04     2021-01-07
```

So in this example, the first row starts with the initial start date (2020-12-16) which is on Wednesday and continues with the new end date(2020-12-18) which is the next Friday, and so on with ranges of working weeks until the actual end date of this period.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```sql
WITH sample_data ( start_date, end_date ) AS (
  SELECT DATE '2020-12-16', DATE '2021-01-07' FROM DUAL
),
weeks ( start_date, week_start, week_end, end_date ) AS (
  SELECT start_date,
         TRUNC( start_date, 'IW' ),
         LEAST( TRUNC( start_date, 'IW' ) + INTERVAL '4' DAY, end_date ),
         end_date
  FROM   sample_data
UNION ALL
  SELECT start_date,
         week_start + INTERVAL '7' DAY,
         LEAST( week_end + INTERVAL '7' DAY, end_date ),
         end_date
  FROM   weeks
  WHERE  week_start + INTERVAL '7' DAY <= end_date
)
SELECT GREATEST( week_start, start_date ) AS new_start_date,
       week_end AS new_end_date
FROM   weeks
WHERE  GREATEST( week_start, start_date ) <= week_end;
```

Which outputs (where the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is `YYYY-MM-DD (DY)`):

> | NEW_START_DATE | NEW_END_DATE |
> | --- | --- |
> | 2020-12-16 (WED) | 2020-12-18 (FRI) |
> | 2020-12-21 (MON) | 2020-12-25 (FRI) |
> | 2020-12-28 (MON) | 2021-01-01 (FRI) |
> | 2021-01-04 (MON) | 2021-01-07 (THU) |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9b5ffb357fc2a810b07aa31825b5dc8a)*

Comment: It appears from minimal testing that you were careful to handle the possibility that the "end date" is a Saturday or Sunday - but did not handle the "start date" the same way. You may want to take a look at that. (That is: if the input "start date" is a Saturday or Sunday, your query leaves it as-is; to be consistent with what you did for the "end date", the "new start date" should probably be the following Monday.)

Comment: @mathguy Thanks, it just needed a filter to ensure that the start of the week is not after the end of the week.

Comment: Thanks for all your help and suggestions. I took into consideration if a "end date" will be on weekends, but I believe this will not happen. Thanks again and everyone have a great weekend.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way - compute the Monday dates for the ISO week of the input dates (`start_date` and `end_date`), while also keeping track of which is the first and which is the last such Monday in the same hierarchical (`connect by`) query. Then produce the requested output; for the first week, check that the `start_date` is not a Saturday or a Sunday (if it is, that "first week" should not produce a row in the output); that is done in the `where` clause. This is illustrated in the sample dates I used for testing - the input "start date" is a Saturday, so the first "new start date" is the following Monday.

```
with
  sample_data (start_date, end_date) as (
    select date '2020-12-12', date '2021-01-02' from dual
  )
, mondays (dt, rn, mx) as (
    select  trunc(start_date, 'iw') + 7 * (level - 1), level, max(level) over ()
    from    sample_data
    connect by level <= 1 + (trunc(end_date, 'iw') - trunc(start_date, 'iw'))/7
  )
select case rn when 1  then greatest(start_date, dt) 
                       else dt     end as new_start_date,
       case rn when mx then least(dt + 4, end_date) 
                       else dt + 4 end as new_end_date
from   sample_data cross join mondays
where  rn >= 2 or start_date <= dt + 4
;

NEW_START_DATE  NEW_END_DATE   
--------------- ---------------
MON 14-DEC-2020 FRI 18-DEC-2020
MON 21-DEC-2020 FRI 25-DEC-2020
MON 28-DEC-2020 FRI 01-JAN-2021
```